# Crystal Reports - Hiding a text and drawing object based on data

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a text and drawing on a Crystal Report which I would like to hide if the data field "IsVisible" is set to 1. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either conditionally suppress the entire section that the fields/text/picture is on by going to 'Section Expert' -> select the section you want -> click the formula button next to 'Suppress (No Drill-Down)' and enter `{field.IsVisible}<>1`, or you can selectively only suppress the fields/text/pictures in question by right-clicking them -> 'Format Field' or 'Format Graphic' -> 'Common' tab -> enter the same suppression formula.