# Programmatically hide text/lines in a Crystal Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report that I populate before displaying to the user using a [`CrystalReportViewer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa665753%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

I have some static text items and line segments that I would like to show and hide programatically depending on conditions in the business logic. Is there a way I can group a bunch of these items together and hide them as a group?

At the moment, my other option is to have two separate reports that are identical except for these superficial differences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By all means, please don't create two separate reports :)

In the Report Design view, you should be able to create sub-sections of your detail section (assuming you're talking about the detail section), right-clicking on the Detail section and selecting "Insert Section Below".

You should now have "Details a" and "Details b" sections.  You can put your text in the "Details b" section, and apply a conditional suppression formula to it.

To conditionally suppress the "Details b" section, right-click on it in the Design View, select "Format section...", click on the button next to the "Suppress" checkbox, and add your formula there.

Comment: The stuff I want to add is *static* text in the report header. Once the report is printed, these static items will be circled or crossed out with a pen.

Comment: That's fine, you can do the same thing in your report header. Just put all of those objects/text fields you want to possibly hide in the new subsection of your report header, and add your business logic to the conditional suppression formula.

Comment: Excellent. I tried adding a second Report Header section but it would not let me do it, but I think I've managed to add *sub* sections, as you suggested. I have not seen these before but I think I can switch them on and off, now.

Comment: The CR user interface is not completely intuitive ;)

Comment: @CharlieSalts - that's an understatement :D

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables One gotcha with Crystal Reports is that it will throw an error if any element is referenced in the formula but missing from the data source.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following steps :

1-Add the required field to the report canvas

2-Right click on the field

3-Select the Format Field menu option

4-On the Common Tab in the Format Editor dialog box, press the Conditional Format button [x+2] button for the Display String option

5-In the Formula Workshop enter the following formula:

```
 if {Tablename.Fieldname}= True then Totext(CurrentFieldValue)

else Totext((CurrentFieldValue)) + " Outstanding"
```

6-Press the [Save & Close] button

7-Press the OK button of the Format Editor dialog box

Comment: These aren't fields I'm adding - just lines and static text. All this is being put into the report header.

Comment: @CharlieSalts here is your answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387354/crystal-reports-hiding-a-text-and-drawing-object-based-on-data